# Chat room, messages scroll to top bug

Tags: bug, chat

I am facing this bug when chatting in a room.

All of a **sudden all messages move to the top, leaving a space**.

**Like below:**

[image]

And everything comes back to normal when I am typing my message.

Comment: OS/Browser/User Scripts?

Comment: win 10 / chrome 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)

Comment: Looks like they just released an update.  Try updating and see what happens.  Upgraded to Version 59.0.3071.86 (Official Build) (64-bit) when I went to check my version

Comment: just done it let you know if i face it again

Comment: Does that mean upgrading "fixed" it?

Comment: @NathanOliver he will notify you it occurs again that is what he said

Comment: @NathanOliver nope I faced it again  (Version 59.0.3071.86 (Official Build) (64-bit))

Comment: This has happened to me always, but it just happens sporadically and almost immediately updates and puts it in "normal mode"

Comment: My case I have to type some **n** number of characters in chat input box to make it normal

Comment: I managed to reproduce it. Lost connection, and regained connection without refreshing the tab. When it was reconnected, I had a white area under the last message. Running Chrome 59.0.3071.86 (64-bit) and win10.